# How can I remove all non-letter characters from a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have:

```
String str = txtInput.getText(); 
String words[] = str.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").split("\\s+");
```

...but I need it to remove numbers as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Narrow your regex to only include non-alphabetic characters (and the space, so you can split) instead.

```
String[] words = str.replaceAll("[^A-za-z ]", "").split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words = str.replaceAll("[0-9]","").split("\\s"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
```

Comment: You'll capture the space in that regex, meaning you won't be able to split on anything anymore.